# Can we use '\n' in assembly?

Tags: x86-16, assembly

Count the number of characters in an input line and terminate if enter is pressed.

```
MOV AX, 1
MOV AL, 0
INPUT:  INT 21H
    INC AL
    CMP DL,'\n'
    JE OUT
    LOOP INPUT
OUT:
```

In the above code I have used `\n`. I am curious if we can use it or I would have to use the ascii code of it? Please help.

Comment: The assembler translates character literals into a number, most likely using ASCII.

Comment: Why don't you try it? Just assemble your code and give it a try!

Comment: Your first sentence sounds like homework. If it is please tag it homework.

Comment: You need to specify what assembler you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends entirely on your assembler. Probably yes, otherwise use an ascii table to translate it (to `0x0A` or `10`) yourself.

You should probably just try assembling it and see whether it works.

Answer (score 2):

`'\n'` is not an assembly language constant.  At least not in most assembly languages.

You will have to convert it directly using the character set in use.  You can safely assume ASCII on almost all modern processors, so `\n` will be 10 (decimal) on most operating systems.  On Windows the two-character sequence 13 and 10 is used.